# migrating from access 2007 to 2013. reference problems with rightfax

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013

Hi I am currently trying to upgrade an access 2007 file to 2013. I have opened it and tried to run it ,unfortunately under  references it does not display "Missing" for me to check. I have added some that work but I am having a "user-defined type not defined" error with

```
' Requires reference to "RightFax COM API Type Library"

    Dim faxSvr As RFCOMAPILib.FaxServer
```

And in the References I do not see any rightfax com API type library to check. Is there something I need to download and add? or is rightFax compeletely removed from access 2013?
Any help appreciated  Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't look like this is a default library in Access, but was likely installed with the Rightfax software. Apparently Access doesn't copy add-on libraries during migration (in some cases at least, specifically when User-level security wizard was used to secure the .mdb file, according to your error) https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310803

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to register the DLL or install the software again - RightFax doesn't come with any version of MS-Access

It's a third party application. RightFax has a COMAPI that uses the file RFCOMAPI.DLL - if you can find it on your old system, and register it, you might just get lucky

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys. I have found the correct DLL files to add to the references. Glad some one left a folder with these files in the old server. Googling for them turned up few results.